# I want to display time in a drop down using PHP. It will be be in chunks like 12:00, 12:15, 12:30 and so on

Tags: php, time

This is the code I am trying but it stops some time as now the value of i = 21 which is not <= 2. What should be the solution?

```
$pdts = array();
for($i = ltrim(date('H'), '0'); $i <= ltrim(date('H', time() + 14400), '0') * 2; $i++) {
    for ($j = 15; $j <= 45; $j += 15) {
        if ($j > ltrim(date('i'), '0') && ltrim(date('H'), '0') == $i) {
            $date  = date("H.i", strtotime("$i:$j"));
            $value = $date."h";
            $pdts[$value] = $date;
        }
    }
    if (ltrim(date('i'), '0') != 0 && ltrim(date('H'), '0') != $i) { 
        $date  = date("H.i", strtotime("$i:00"));
        $value = $date."h";
        $pdts[$value] = $date;
    }
    for ($k = 15; $k <= 45; $k += 15) {
        if (ltrim(date('H'), '0') != $i) {
            $date  = date("H.i", strtotime("$i:$k"));
            $value = $date . "h";
            $pdts[$value] = $date;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You really could not make this any more complicated if you tried. Look at [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php)

Comment: I am new to php so I did what I can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand you're trying to get 15-minutes chunks for the next 4 hours. There is built-in PHP DateTime / DateInterval / [DatePeriod](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php) classes just for that. You can use them like that:

```
// current time - beginning of chunks
$begin = new DateTime();

// adjust $begin time for next '15/30/45/00' chunk
$next = $begin->format("i") % 15;
if ($next !== 0) {
    $begin->modify('+' . (15 - $next) . 'minutes');
}

// time of last chunk
$end = clone $begin;
$end->modify("+4 hours");

// chunk interval (15 minutes)
$interval = new DateInterval('PT15M');
// date / time period onject
$timeRange = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);

$pdts = array();
foreach($timeRange as $time){
    $pdts[] = $time->format("H:i");
}
```

Few words about code above:

1.Get current date & time. Current time is the beggining of time period to generate 15-minutes chuncks:

```
$begin = new DateTime();
```

2.Adjust current time to one of the 15-minutes chuncks. The easiest way to do it is to devide current amount of minutes by 15. If the reminder of devision is zero - than current time is OK and we can start from it. Otherwise we need to add `(15 - reminder)` minutes to current time to get valid start time:

```
$next = $begin->format("i") % 15;
if ($next !== 0) {
    $begin->modify('+' . (15 - $next) . 'minutes');
}
```

3.To get end time of time period we need to add 4 hours to start time:

```
$end = clone $begin;
$end->modify("+4 hours");
```

4.We need to create time interval object with chunk duration:

```
$interval = new DateInterval('PT15M');
```

5.Create date period object (it will do all job for us)

```
$timeRange = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);
```

6.Iterate through date period object to gett all chunks

```
$pdts = array();
foreach($timeRange as $time){
    $pdts[] = $time->format("H:i");
}
```

Comment: Thanks a million. This is what I want